# Recording file with AVAudioRecorder, unable to get path to file after recording

Tags: avfoundation, avaudiosession, avaudiorecorder

Here is the code that I use to make the audio file, everything seems to be working fine here:

```
func startRecording() {
    let audioFilename = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("Meeting_Audio.m4a")

    let settings = [
        AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
        AVSampleRateKey: 12000,
        AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 1,
        AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.high.rawValue
    ]

    do {
        audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: audioFilename, settings: settings)
        audioRecorder.delegate = self
        audioRecorder.record()

    } catch {
        finishRecording(success: false)
    }
}

func audioRecorderDidFinishRecording(_ recorder: AVAudioRecorder, successfully flag: Bool) {
    makeFileData()
}


@IBAction func onEndMeetingButtonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
    finishRecording(success: true)
}

func finishRecording(success: Bool) {
    audioRecorder.stop()
    audioRecorder = nil

    if success {
        print("recording succeeded :)")
    } else {
        print("recording failed :(")
    }
}
```

And here is a simplified version of my function that still reproduces the problem.  I am calling this function from `audioRecorderDidFinishRecording`. I can't seem to get the filepath.

```
func makeFileData() {

    if let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Meeting_Audio", ofType: "m4a"){
        print("File path loaded.")

        if let fileData = NSData(contentsOfFile: filePath) {
            print("File data loaded.")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're writing the file to one place:

```
// Documents directory!
let audioFilename = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("Meeting_Audio.m4a")
```

and reading it from another:

```
// app bundle!
let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Meeting_Audio", ofType: "m4a")
```

Try reading the file from the location you wrote to, something like this:

```
if let fileUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Meeting_Audio", withExtension: "m4a"){
    print("File path loaded.")

    if let fileData = NSData(contentsOf: fileUrl) {
        print("File data loaded.")
    }
}
```